# Apostol Problem :Compute $T(4i -j + k)$ and determine the nullity and rank of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem taken from *Tom M Apostol*  Calculas  Vol $:2$  page no $: 50$

A linear transformation $T: V_3 \rightarrow V_2$ maps the basis vectors as follows:

$T(i) = (0, 0)$ ,

$T(j) =(1, 1)$,

$T(k) = (1, -1).$

$(a)$ Compute $T(4i -j + k)$ and determine the nullity and rank of $T$.

My attempt : I got $T(4i-j+k)=(0,-2)$

I got the matrix $T= \begin{bmatrix} 0 &1&1\\0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}$

Here Rank of $T=2$ ,Nullity $T = 0$

Is its true ?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way - $\operatorname{rank} T=\operatorname{dim range} T\leq \dim V_2=2$, but $\operatorname{nullity} T =\dim \operatorname{span}(1,0,0)=1$ so that $\operatorname{rank} T=2$.

Answer (score 1):

The nullity is $1$, you computed the rank well.

Else $\dim V=3=\operatorname{nullity} T+ \operatorname{rank} T=0+2$